# Please give suggestions to improve question on Josh Waitzkin further

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open

[Josh Waitzkin on trading pieces ('the art of the trade')](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34038/edited-to-hopefully-re-open-please-josh-waitzkin-chessmaster-part-on-trading-p)

Rewan Demontay and I have already edited the above question. So far there are only 2 re-open votes (vs the apparently only 1 close vote needed. so much for '[Chess Stack Exchange doesn't see much questions per day or traffic, so we don't have the luxury to close questions](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/952)', though I guess the context is different...which might be seen at the end of the sentence...)

Please make suggestions to further improve question, so it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-opened already. thank you

> Rewan Demontay, GloriaVictis, lodebari, double-beep, Laska

notably missing the CLOSER(/s) of the post.

Comment: One can see that data? You live, you learn :-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann maybe it's a new feature? (not 2021 new. maybe 2017 new. idk)